# Running typescript compiler inside a browser

Tags: typescript, webassembly

We are creating an webbased designer/editor for our ERP suite.
All forms that are designed get stored inside a database to make everything lazyloading.
Our base system is made in angular. There we made a loadable module system using json streaming to define forms.

Eventhandling inside the forms is now done with javascript that can be attached to eventthandlers.
This javascript can be written inside our designer so we can make a complete cloudbased development tool.
I am now investigating if it is also possible to use typescript instead of javascript.
For this we need to be able to run the typescript compiler inside the browser.
Is this possible? for example is there somewhere a project that has wasm as compile target for the typescript compiler so the compiler can be loaded and run inside the browser

Comment: Here you have a docs for Compiler API https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Some methods you are able to run in browser

Comment: have you checked https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/typescript-vfs/

Comment: tnx for the links will look into them to see if we can use them somehow